# How to detect UilLabel contain tail "..." IOS/Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm using

titleLabel.Lines = 2;
titleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;

Now long text is broken by a ... in the end.

Now I would like to know if the titleLabel is tail truncated , contains "..." ? Any easy suggestions for this ?? as I cannot see the ... characters in the actual titleLabel.Text field

Comment: Why would you need to know this?

Comment: I need to make the ... in a different colour :)

Comment: you wanna color the truncation symbol only or the whole label text

Comment: only the truncation ... symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [Change the default '...' at the end of a text if the content of a UILabel doesn't fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392217/change-the-default-at-the-end-of-a-text-if-the-content-of-a-uilabel-doesn)

There is no direct option to access `ellipsis`(the three dot). You need to do it yourself. Code to count the size of your string, clip the string and add a ellipsis with the color you want when the string exceed the view.

**Define a `NSAttributesString`**

```
let atttext = NSAttributedString(string: text!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
```

**Calculate the size of the string**

```
let bounds = atttext.boundingRectWithSize(label.bounds.size, options: [], context: nil)
```

**Do something to the string when it exceed the view**

```
if bounds.size.width > 10 {
    //Do something here, like assign a new value to `attributedText` of label or change the color
    label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Labelfdjkfdsjkfdsjkf...", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
}
```

For more detail, you can have a look at the last answer of the question I mentioned above.