# How to determine if a certain text is being completely shown in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to know if a certain text is being completely shown in the textLabel of a UITableViewCell?

I mean: is it possible to find out if the ellipsis (dot dot dot) had to be shown because the text was to long to fit in the textLabel?

I am thinking of showing the accesoryDetailButton to let the user see the whole text if it didn't fit.

Comment: No mean... already changed

Comment: @Daniel Martín: the tag xcode makes no sense. It doesnt matter, if the code was written in xcode, vim or by using a telegraph

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. Really helpful :). Now... anybody has the answer to the question ;)

Comment: Do you allow the text font size to change?

Comment: No I don't Rikkles. That is not what I want. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's easier if you have a fixed text font size, that's why I was asking.

Comment: Ah, ok, understood. Thanks. I think I'll try arun.s answer (the first one).

Comment: Yes but check my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of the string like this -

```
CGSize textSize = [title sizeWithFont:titleFont 
                         constrainedToSize:textLabelSize 
                             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

Compare the size with your `tableViewCell` `textlabel` `frame size`.

If greater then it is having ellipsis else not.

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: don't use contentCellSize. Use textLabel.bounds.size

Comment: Ya tanx .. i will correct the variable name .. didn't notice the variable name  !!!

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a custom truncating class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793420/how-to-change-truncate-characters-in-uilabel/15020409#15020409) if you use it, it will return a bool that will tell you if it truncated for not