# 'advancedBy' is unavailable in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Currently, I've been using XCode 8 and on the line

```
let range = key.startIndex...key.startIndex.advancedBy(0)
```

I get the error:

> error: 'advancedBy' is unavailable: To advance an index by n steps call 'index(_:offsetBy:)' on the CharacterView instance that produced the index.

How can I fix this?

A screenshot of the error is below:

[image: advancedBy is unavailable]

Comment: Please include your code in the question as well as the screenshot.

Comment: You need to use index offsetBy http://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md

Answer (score 23):

`advancedBy(_:)` has been deprecated in Swift v3 and replaced by `index(_:offsetBy:)`. Refer to Apple's [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) for more info.

The solution to your error:

```
let range = key.startIndex...key.index(key.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are after more simply by building a new string rather than manipulating the old one:

```
let upperCasedFirstCharacter = String(key.characters.first!).uppercased()

let remainder = key.substring(from: key.characters.index(after: key.characters.startIndex))

let selector = "set\(upperCasedFirstCharacter)\(remainder)"
```