# Got error of advancedBy on Swift3 conversion

Tags: swift3

I'm converting my Swift2.3 code to Swift3, and got an error at the line where I used advancedBy. XCode showing me a replacing code that using offsetBy, but I still don't understand.

```
func unhideEmaimage(_ imageFile: String) {
    let dotLocation = imageFile.characters.index(of: ".")

    self.emaImage.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageFile)

    if dotLocation != nil {
        let filenameInitial = imageFile.startIndex
        let filenameLast = dotLocation!.advancedBy(-1)
        let filenamePart:String = imageFile[filenameInitial...filenameLast]
    }
```

And, following is the code that XCode showing me how to fix the error. However, I still don't know how to modify.

```
let filenameLast = "String.CharacterView corresponding to your index".index(dotLocation!, offsetBy: -1)
```

Please let me know the way to fix this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [advancedBy is unavailable in Xcode 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449379/advancedby-is-unavailable-in-xcode-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Write this:

```
let filenameLast = imageFile.index(dotLocation!,offsetBy: -1)
```