# Setting vertical align of truncated tails for NSAttributedString with NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, alignment, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I'm using the following code to generate a `NSAttributedString` for `UILabel` in iOS 8.

```
// a long long Chinese title 
NSString *title = @"这是一个很长很长很长很长很长很长的中文标题";
// setup icon attachment
NSTextAttachment *iconAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
iconAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
iconAttachment.bounds = bounds;
NSAttributedString *ycardImageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:iconAttachment];

// setup attributed text
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
if (shouldShowYcard) {
    [attributedText insertAttributedString:ycardImageString atIndex:0];
    [attributedText insertAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "] atIndex:1];
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(offset) range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
}
NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(shouldShowYcard ? 2 : 0, title.length);
[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:titleRange];
[attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:titleRange];
```

However it seems that the `NSTextAttachment` will effect the vertical position of truncated tails, just like the following pictures.

[image: NSAttributedString with NSTextAttachment]
[image: NSAttributedString without NSTextAttachment]
[image: NSAttributedString with NSTextAttachment In English]
[image: NSAttributedString without NSTextAttachment In English]

Is there a way to set the vertical aignment for the truncated tails?

My goal is to have bottom align tails in Chinese language.

This is an icon for test.[image: icon]

Comment: Did You upload your screen shot that shows a english language text ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I just upload the screen shot in English.  But it seems to be a Chinese only bug...

Comment: in your screen shot its shows dot. because of your text length big and you need same output with vertical alignment right ?

Comment: Yes. I need both of them in the bottom, just like the English version.

Comment: What do you want? Just explian in brief

Comment: @Jecky I want to have bottom align tails when showing Chinese title. You can see in the picture that currently the Chinese title have a middle align tail.

Comment: @xi.lin Check My answer

Comment: @xi.lin Check out my updated answer, I update it as you want

Comment: @Jecky It still not work in my app. Could you use my recently uploaded icon file to have a try and show the screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126003/discussion-between-jecky-and-xi-lin).

Comment: @Jecky OK. I'm in.

Comment: @xi.lin Check out my updated answer

Comment: @xi.lin Now Its perfectly working with image

Comment: @xi.lin Did you try it ?

Comment: @Jecky Yes, I've tried. Your code and my original code both works well in iOS 10. But they both failed in iOS 8.

Comment: @xi.lin I have given you right answer for ios 10 . Would you like to approve for others ? Actually I try this code in ios 9.3 in xcode 7.3 and its working perfectly.

Comment: @Jecky In fact my sample code works well in iOS9/iOS10 too. I can give you an upvote but I cannot approve it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, No problem. My help just worth to you Thats enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I choose a ugly way to fix this problem by setting `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` for truncate tail.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793420/how-to-change-truncate-characters-in-uilabel) is a way to calculate the truncate part. But in my case, my label width is fixed so that I can directly set the range for control.

```
if (title.length > 10 && ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 9.0)) {
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(-4) range:NSMakeRange(9, 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this One

```
   UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 300, 300, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    NSString *t= @"这是一个很长很长很长很长很长很长的中文标题漢字";
    NSTextAttachment *iconatt = [[NSTextAttachment alloc]init];
    iconatt.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"phnzY.png"];
    iconatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 22);

    NSAttributedString *ycardstring = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:iconatt];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:t];
    [attributedText insertAttributedString:ycardstring atIndex:0];
    [attributedText insertAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "] atIndex:1];
     [attributedText addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(0.0) range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange( 0 , t.length);
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0] range:titleRange];
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:titleRange];
    lbl.attributedText = attributedText;
```

**It will Give output Like this**
[image: output]

Comment: it didn't work. Your code gives the output since you haven't insert `ycardstring` into `y10` or `y11`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use NSMutableParagraphStyle to set the paragraphStyle.
Here is the Code:

```
    let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30))
    let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 90, width: 100, height: 30))
    view.addSubview(label1)
    view.addSubview(label2)
    let t = "12341421dsadyusatdiuwtquyidtywatyudigsaydgsadysaghdkgaugduiyyudgasgdj"
    let iconAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    iconAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "caseEditorBtn0")
    iconAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30);
    let ycardImageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment)
    let yT0 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: t)
    let yT1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: t)

    let p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    p.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail //set line break model
    p.alignment = .right                //set aligment
    yT1.setAttributes([NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: p], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: yT1.length))
    yT0.setAttributes([NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: p], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: yT0.length))
    //insert you custom text attachment at last, or it may be not show
    yT0.insert(ycardImageString, at: 0) 

    label1.attributedText =  yT0
    label2.attributedText = yT1
```

Comment: I tried to set a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` with `lineBreakMode`, but it didn't work on Chinese text.

Comment: I found that my problem is on iOS 8 only