# iOS How to set background image for text in UILabel/UITextView?

Tags: ios, user-interface, iosdeployment

As the picture I marked in red Rect, how to implement it?

1. The image and text in the same line;
2. The text can wrap to the first column;

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what part exactly is causing you trouble, `NSAttributedString` can add colors, images to UILabel/UITextView.

Comment: yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Your image name")!)

Comment: Hey, please take a look at the picture in my question. The text can wrap to the first column

Comment: @Raniys What do you exactly want? You want an image with label and some particular word in color ?

Comment: @Raniys Please follow my answer into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643542/setting-vertical-align-of-truncated-tails-for-nsattributedstring-with-nstextatta/40105498#40105498

Comment: Potentially, it's just a custom `UITableViewCell`, with an image, and text, and the level image, the rest, and just using constraint, and excludedPath, they manage to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the question as @Jecky Modi's suggestion, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643542/setting-vertical-align-of-truncated-tails-for-nsattributedstring-with-nstextatta/40105498#40105498) for it.