# Can I change the location of the ellipsis on the uilabel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I used UiLabel with byTruncatingTail attribute.
I want to fix the ellipsis from the middle to the bottom vertically.

It is now stated as follows.
[image: is as]

But I want to have the ellipsis placed on the floor as follows.
[image: to be]

My code is as follows.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedString.length)
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
titleLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643542/setting-vertical-align-of-truncated-tails-for-nsattributedstring-with-nstextatta